# Toolbar button labels

Tags: swift, xcode, uistoryboard, uitoolbar

How to add labels (captions) to buttons on toolbar? With tabbar it is very straightforward - I just set the titles for "Bar items" and they are there, but I cannot set it on toolbar this way.

I prefer storyboard approach over coding one.

Comment: thank you, @the4kman, i'm just checking the solution and probably close the question soon

Comment: tadam! At least I learned something along the way - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled :)